# Is there a better way to make sure an element outside of a matrix isn't accessed?

Tags: c, performance, matrix, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I am coding the game checkers in C using the Ncurses library and I have all the pieces stored in a matrix, g.board, and when looking for possible moves I need to make sure the program doesn't try and access an element outside of the matrix, because segmentation faults. I have a solution, but it feels rather crude and I have the feeling there is a more elegant way to do this, but I can't find or think of it.

*`int x` and `int y` refer the x and y location in that matrix that I want to look for possible moves around. `char ck` just tells me if the piece is a king a color, the normal colors can only move in one direction. `g.board[y][x].possible` just is bool variable in the structure that tells me if it's a possible move.*

```
void checkPossible(int y, int x, char ck);
{
    bool left = false, right = false, top = false, bottem = false;

    // Dertimes if a tile is out of bounds 
    if (y != 0)
    {
        top = true;        
    }
    if (y != 8)
    {
        bottem = true;
    }
    if (x != 0)
    }
        left = true;
    }
    if (x != 8)
    {
        right = true;
    {

    // Sets g.board.possible to true if possible move
    if ((top == true && left == true) && (ck == 'k' || ck == 'w'))
    {
        g.board[y - 1][x - 1].possible = true; 
    }
    if ((top == true && right == true) && (ck == 'k' || ck == 'w'))
    {
        g.board[y - 1][x + 1].possible = true; 
    }
    if ((bottem == true && left == true) && (ck == 'k' || ck == 'r'))
    {
        g.board[y + 1][x - 1].possible = true; 
    }
    if ((bottem == true && right == true) && (ck == 'k' || ck == 'r'))
    {
        g.board[y + 1][x + 1].possible = true; 
    }
}
```

As far as I know it works, I haven't tested it much, but it feels crude.
*I apologize for any mistakes or less than optimal coding, I am rather new to this.*

Comment: `g.board[y - 1][x - 1].possible == true;` should use `=`, not `==`.

Comment: I don't get `if (y != 0){top = true;}`. If y is NOT 0 then you are at the top?

Comment: Because of `if (x != 0)}` and `{right = true;{` I suspect that you never successfully compiled this. Please double check that the code you show is closely enough related to what you are working on. Maybe try for a [mcve]. On the other hand, the question is more of a "please review" type than is appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Yunnosch I think it means "If y is not 0, then the element on top of this one is inside the board".

Comment: Please improve your question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55946497/edit)ing it to provide some [MCVE]

Comment: Don't write things like `if (bottom == true)`. Just write `if (bottom)`.

Comment: Your algorithm seems fine. There are lots of ways to improve the coding style. I suggest you post it on [codereview.se] for comments.

Comment: For instance, `top = y != 0;` instead of using `if`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, a way of reading it was all I needed. (no sarcasm intended)

Comment: If you have complete working code that you want feedback on, codereview.stackexchange.com is the right place to go. You will be amazed on the amount of feedback you can get there. Do note that when you post there, the code should work. It's not for finding bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing looks very fishy. `g.board[y - 1][x - 1].possible == true` should be `g.board[y - 1][x - 1].possible = true`. The current code does nothing.

The code is also VERY overly complicated. Look at this:

```
void checkPossible(int y, int x, char ck);
{
    bool left = x != 0, 
         right = x != 8, 
         top = y !=8, 
         bottem = y!=0;

    // Sets g.board.possible to true if possible move
    if(ck == 'k' || ck == 'w') {
        g.board[y - 1][x - 1].possible = (top && left);
        g.board[y - 1][x + 1].possible = (top && right);
        g.board[y + 1][x - 1].possible = (bottem && left);
        g.board[y + 1][x + 1].possible = (bottem && right);
    }
}
```

In general, don't compare Boolean variables to the Boolean constants true and false or other values. Use them directly as is instead, and give them descriptive names.

Also, I would (probably, because I have not seen the rest of the code) split checking of coordinates and character. The less functionality you put in a single function, the easier it is to understand, maintain and name. Like this:

```
bool isValidCoordinate(int y, int x) {
    return y>=0 && y<=8 && x>=0 && x<=8;
}

bool isValidCharacter(char ck) {
    return ck == 'k' || ck == 'w';
}
```

I don't know if that would fit into your project, but it gives an idea of how you can do it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that error, I fixed that in the programme.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the values themselves. I have never seen code like that, It makes sense I just didn't know it was possible, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to make sure an element outside of a matrix isn't accessed?

The only reliable way to do that in C is to check (at runtime) the indexes used to access the matrix, or to prove (before compilation) that this cannot happen. Tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) could help you in making such a proof. However, be aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Accessing an element outside (the range of the array containing that element) is some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So if you do that, *anything* can happen (and that sadly includes that no observable behavior is impacted), so be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

On Linux, you might also use [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) at runtime. It is very often quite helpful.

Your code could be wrong if `x` was negative (or above the dimension of your checker board). You'll better also check that case or prove that it cannot happen.

See also [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html). You might want to use it (it can do runtime checks).

PS. You really should understand what *undefined behavior* means (even as a newbie programmer). Read [*What Every C Programmer Should Know about Undefined Behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html). Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you use some [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and debug info. Improve your code to get no warnings, then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (or else whatever debugger you have).

Comment: That's what he's doing, isn't it? He's just asking if there's a better way to code it.

Comment: Yes, as I answered, a proof.

Comment: I don't think he really explained his problem well. He's not worried about `x` and `y` inputs being invalid. He's testing neighbors of `x` and `y`, and wants to make sure he doesn't go outside when they're at an edge.

Comment: **Your code could be wrong if x was negative** If I understand what he's doing, `x` can never be negative. He just wants to know which neighbors of x,y are inside the board.

Comment: We don't have any [MCVE], so I have no idea if `x` could be negative or not

Comment: Thank you, but that is way above my level, but I really appreciate the feedback, I will look into them.

Comment: Read more about *undefined behavior*; it is a very important concept in C, even for beginners. It probably is the most important thing to learn when programming in C.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I don't see any runtime checks on `x`